# Syntax Errors On Multi Picklist Validation

Tags: validation, multi-select

I'm attempting to write a simple opportunity validation rule that states if the `Reasons for loss` multipicklist field includes `Lack of Functionality` then a text field called `Functionality lost to` must not be blank.

Here is my current attempt (fairly new to this), but I'm getting errors

> Extra: ISBLANK

Could someone check this and tell me the formula I'm looking for?

```
AND(

INCLUDES(Reason_for_Loss_New__c, "Lack of Functionality"),

ISBLANK(Functionality_Lost_On__c))
```

Comment: this looks good to me. are you sure this validation rule is not compiling?

Comment: I tried it in my org and was able to save the validation rule without any error.Can you try again